# what's the simplest way to calculate the sum of values at the end of this jq command?

Tags: bash, jq

I see that `jq` can calculate addition as simply as `jq 'map(.duration) | add'` but I've got a more complex command and I can't figure out how to perform this `add` at the end of it.

I'm starting with data like this:

```
{
  "object": "list",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "in_1HW85aFGUwFHXzvl8wJbW7V7",
      "object": "invoice",
      "account_country": "US",
      "customer_name": "clientOne",
      "date": 1601244686,
      "livemode": true,
      "metadata": {},
      "paid": true,
      "status": "paid",
      "total": 49500
    },
    {
      "id": "in_1HJlIZFGUwFHXzvlWqhegRkf",
      "object": "invoice",
      "account_country": "US",
      "customer_name": "clientTwo",
      "date": 1598297143,
      "livemode": true,
      "metadata": {},
      "paid": true,
      "status": "paid",
      "total": 51000
    },
    {
      "id": "in_1HJkg5FGUwFHXzvlYp2uC63C",
      "object": "invoice",
      "account_country": "US",
      "customer_name": "clientThree",
      "date": 1598294757,
      "livemode": true,
      "metadata": {},
      "paid": true,
      "status": "paid",
      "total": 57000
    },
    {
      "id": "in_1H8B0pFGUwFHXzvlU6nrOm6I",
      "object": "invoice",
      "account_country": "US",
      "customer_name": "clientThree",
      "date": 1595536051,
      "livemode": true,
      "metadata": {},
      "paid": true,
      "status": "paid",
      "total": 20000
    }
  ],
  "has_more": true,
  "url": "/v1/invoices"
}
```

and my `jq` command looks like:

```
cat example-data.json | 
  jq -C '[.data[] 
          | {invoice_id: .id, client: .customer_name, date: .date | strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), amount: .total, status: .status}
          | .amount = "$" + (.amount/100|tostring)]
         | sort_by(.date)'
```

which nicely gives me output like:

```
[
  {
    "invoice_id": "in_1H8B0pFGUwFHXzvlU6nrOm6I",
    "client": "clientThree",
    "date": "2020-07-23",
    "amount": "$200",
    "status": "paid"
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "in_1HJlIZFGUwFHXzvlWqhegRkf",
    "client": "clientTwo",
    "date": "2020-08-24",
    "amount": "$510",
    "status": "paid"
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "in_1HJkg5FGUwFHXzvlYp2uC63C",
    "client": "clientThree",
    "date": "2020-08-24",
    "amount": "$570",
    "status": "paid"
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "in_1HW85aFGUwFHXzvl8wJbW7V7",
    "client": "clientOne",
    "date": "2020-09-27",
    "amount": "$495",
    "status": "paid"
  }
]
```

and I want to add a sum/total at the end of that, something like `Total: $1775`, so that the entire output would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "invoice_id": "in_1H8B0pFGUwFHXzvlU6nrOm6I",
    "client": "clientThree",
    "date": "2020-07-23",
    "amount": "$200",
    "status": "paid"
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "in_1HJlIZFGUwFHXzvlWqhegRkf",
    "client": "clientTwo",
    "date": "2020-08-24",
    "amount": "$510",
    "status": "paid"
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "in_1HJkg5FGUwFHXzvlYp2uC63C",
    "client": "clientThree",
    "date": "2020-08-24",
    "amount": "$570",
    "status": "paid"
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "in_1HW85aFGUwFHXzvl8wJbW7V7",
    "client": "clientOne",
    "date": "2020-09-27",
    "amount": "$495",
    "status": "paid"
  }
]
Total: $1775
```

Is there a neat/tidy way to enhance this `jq` command to achieve this?
Or even, since I'm invoking this in a shell script, a dirty/ugly way with bash?

Comment: Aside: Passing your code in a double-quoted string makes readers do a lot more work than they would if you were using a single-quoted string (everything in a single-quoted string is obviously parsed as literal, things in a double-quoted string need to be considered for whether they contain expansions). And with single quotes on the outside, you don't need all the added backslashes.

Comment: Anyhow -- is it important to you that the JSON content is pretty-printed onto multiple lines with indentation?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I changed doublequotes to single.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy pretty-printing is helpful to distinguish between key/label and value.  But I'm not too concerned about the indentation etc.  Performance/efficiency isn't crucial, though it'd be great to only do the `cat example.json` once because I'm actually `curl`ing a remote API.

Comment: _nod_, I'd hope that for a real-world use you'd be using `jq ... <example.json` or `jq ... example.json` but otherwise not using cat.

Comment: @alec - Do you really want your nice JSON polluted with non-JSON?  If neither JSON nor a JSON-stream is acceptable, have you considered sending the non-JSON to stderr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you decide after all to emit valid JSON, here is a modular answer to the question that makes it easy to formulate alternative approaches, and which postpones the conversion of `.amount` to dollars for efficiency:

```
def todollar:
  "$" + tostring;
  
def json:
  [.data[]
   | {invoice_id: .id,
      client: .customer_name,
      date: .date | strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
      amount: (.total/100),
      status: .status} ]
  | sort_by(.date) ;

json
| map_values(.amount |= todollar),
  "Total: " + (map(.amount) | add | todollar)
```

As noted elsewhere, you will probably want to use the -r command-line option.

Answer (score 4):

If *any* of your output is going to be raw, you need to pass `-r`; it'll just be ignored for data items that aren't strings.

Anyhow -- if you write `(expr1, expr2)`, then your input will be passed through both expressions. Thus:

```sh
jq -Cr '
  ([.data[]
    | {invoice_id: .id,
       client: .customer_name,
       date: .date | strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
       amount: .total,
       status: .status}
    | .amount = "$" + (.amount/100|tostring)
   ] | sort_by(.date)),
  "Total: $\([.data[] | .total] | add | . / 100)"
'
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Since introducing `$input` here really does nothing other than naming `.`, you might like to consider dropping it altogether to produce a more "jq-esqe" (and shorter) solution.  If you decide to retain it, the first use could still be eliminated.

Comment: The only significant potential for inefficiency that I can see in your approach is that the space for `.` (the initial input) cannot be freed as early as it could be if Total were computed from the intermediate result instead of from the initial input.  This is highlighted by the reappearance of $input in the last line, but would not change if the explicit reference were dropped.

Comment: @peak, yes, that's the concern I was communicating to the OP; a reducer could generate both a running total and the output list in one pass, instead of needing to hold onto the whole document.

Comment: And my point is that you wouldn't need a single reducer to overcome the main source of inefficiency (retaining the memory).  In fact, given the way jq works, I would expect that the `A | (B,C)` approach illustrated by my answer on this page would be faster than the single-reducer solution (`reduce` is quite slow).

Comment: Interesting! Seems I'd made some inaccurate assumptions about the execution model.

Comment: Regarding speed, there's nothing deeper here 
 than that compiled code is fast.